# No puedo invocar una función en el Main

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy con un WindowsForms de C# y tengo un problema en la clase Program.cs a la hora de intentar invocar una función creada en otra clase. El caso es que tengo esta clase:

```html
namespace Fotos
{
    public partial class Creacion : Form
    {
        public string GifPath = @"\Fotos\Análisis Completos\";
        public MagickImageCollection gif = new MagickImageCollection();
        public Creacion(string nombre1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string Path = @"\Fotos\";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*"+nombre1+".cs", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (var element in files)
            {
                gif.Add(element);
                gif[gif.Count - 1].AnimationDelay = 250;
            }

            timer2.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Start();
            timer2.Interval = 1000;
            progressBar2.Maximum = 35;
            timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);

            gif.Optimize();
            gif.Write(GifPath + nombre1 + ".gif");
            gif.Clear();
        }
```

Y estoy intentando en el Program.cs en el Main hacer una llamada para ejecutar esa función:

```
       public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 0)
            {
                Creacion(string nombre1);
                return;
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

            Application.Run(new Fotos());
        }
```

Comment: Creacion es una funcion de la clase `Fotos`?

Comment: Creacion es una clase y tambien una parcial, actualizo el codigo para que quede mas claro

Comment: tendrás que instanciarlo `Creacion NombreQueQuieras = new Creacion(nombre);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás intentando llamar una clase sin inicializarla, por lo que veo en el código si te pasan argumentos llamas a `Creacion` que hereda de `Form` y, sino llamas a `Fotos`, por lo que creo que tu código debería quedar así:

```
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 0)
        {
            Application.Run(new Creacion(args[0]));
            return;
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

        Application.Run(new Fotos());
    }
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias por la ayuda, era algo básico pero que no me había fijado